# Need some help to create .jar file using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

I downloaded NetBeans 6.5 complete pack with Java ME. And then I downloaded and installed Sun Java Wireless Toolkit too. And I have tried in all ways to go to New Project -> And in under Java ME -> Mobile Application

Then I enter name and location.

And then when to select the emulator platform, "Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC" is there.

But when I press NEXT nothing happens. A red sign just blinks on the background!

I want to create a jar file to be run on Sony Ericsson phones!

How do I do it?

Comment: What does the dialog say when you click on the flashing red sign? It should let you see an exception stack trace; can you post that here?

Comment: what operating system are you running netbeans on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few things to try:

- check/uncheck the "create Hello MIDlet" option
- check/uncheck the "set as main project" option
- change the project name in case it conflicts with another in the same location
- only use basic characters in the project name: [A..Z][a..z][0..9]
- make very very sure the project location you're using is correct for your operating system.